# Relational database w/ images for ios application

Tags: ios, image, relational-database

I am currently developing an iOS application that will need to be able to both upload and download images from a remote database; in addition, it will need to be able to cite and update stats associated with said images - e.g. comments, etc. (That is, i think it will need to be a relational database.)
Any suggestions on how I might go about this/which frameworks/apis are best to use? it seems that Amazon's s3 service, while it is great for uploading and downloading, would not be as easy to store information along with images that would be easily searched; likewise, it 'parse' seems to be a good service for the backend, but it has the same issues. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is to have a php server with a web service that have the connection with the relational DB. Your application will connect to this web service to GET/POST/DELETE/PUT data. The server will send this information and you will parse it with a JSON tool.
I recommend you to use Restkit for the IOS side, it will make your life very easy:

> http://www.Restkit.org

You can use Symphony on the server side, it's a php framework very easy to use:

> http://www.symfony-project.org/

I hope this will help you!